# Stack Overflow should include screen shot options for each question

Tags: feature-request, screenshot

It would be a good idea to add a screenshot option in Stack Exchange for each question.  It would allow a user to upload an error message/exception/or any related problem screenshot.

Comment: @Chris you made a mistake here.... unless there's a super hidden easter egg nobody is aware of that allows us to take screenshots?

Comment: @Shadow Well you can upload images now and the previous answers suggest you couldn't before

Comment: @RichardTingle yes but there's a huge gap, in my opinion at least, between uploading a picture and "screenshot option".... that's not what was asked here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not disagreeing, but I think the sane middle ground has been found between the two extremes (p.s. it concerns me that my phone has now learned @ shadowWizard as an autocomplete word)

Comment: @RichardTingle lol about your phone... AI is taking over! ;)

Comment: @Martin isn't this radical change? I still think the OP here actually meant a button that will automatically take screenshot when clicked. Can you find proof he meant what others here think?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - `It will allow to upload error message/exception/or any related problem screen shot.` surely means they are just asking about image upload? Also the answer they accepted would be entirely irrelevant for that interpretation.

Comment: I think I agree with @ShadowWizard here; It *seemed* to me the person was specifically looking for a way to integrate the screenshot/uploading process. That's the way I read the original, anyway.

Comment: (the above also /cc @MartinSmith)

Comment: @AndrewBarber question is what to do then? The OP doesn't show signs of coming back. Rolling back the title and removing the status-completed was my initial thought but now I'm not sure. :(

Comment: Well as none of the answers address the issue at all of exporting as screen shots (irrespective of what the original intention was) and all agree with my interpretation surely it should just remain as is. The export can then be raised as a different question in the future.

Comment: That's my feeling, too, @sha. I suspect there are other posts about image upload around, anyway

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Oh I see your interpretation is different from what I thought ShadowWizard was saying. I thought he was saying that the OP wanted a way to export SO content as a screenshot. Similar to fireshot functionality. You think they wanted some sort of application/plugin that would take a screenshot and upload it in one fell swoop? Still none of the answers specifically address that aspect anyway though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StackOverflow isn't an image hoster, nor will it be. It's practically being run out of Jeff's basement off of a single server, which is almost reaching CPU capacity as it is. Image hosting is way too expensive when there are so many folks out there who do it for free.

Pick your favorite:

- http://imgur.com
- http://flickr.com

Comment: Based on what I read and hear, this site is hardly run out of his basement.  Perhaps you are thinking of his blog?

Comment: @tim: I was being sarcastic...the site *is* running off of a single server, though, and they are looking at adding another one.

Comment: The site is being run off multiple servers: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/new-stack-overflow-server-glamour-shots/

Comment: +1 because people seem to be missing  your point.

Answer (score 6):

Error messages and exceptions shouldn't be shown in screenshots. They should be cut and pasted as *text*.

Having an option for image storage in general is an interesting idea, although it would be very prone to abuse. There are plenty of other sites where you can upload images, and then paste a URL into SO. You end up with the *potential* for dead links, admittedly.

Comment: Except for all those wonderful diaglogs that don't support mark & copy.

Answer (score 2):

Error message can be copied, and pasted. Design-issues with HTML/CSS benefit greatly from screenshots - http://www.doctype.com (similar to SO, but for design-questions) gives you the ability to post screenshots of your design with your question ([example](http://doctype.com/ie7-text-issues)).

Answer (score 2):

At most I would like a redirect.

---

```
http://stackoverflow.com/api/userimage/{userid}/{photoid}.301
http://stackoverflow.com/api/userimage.301?userid={userid}&photoid={photoid}
```

Could redirect to where you have posted the image.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/api/userimage/{userid}/{photoid}.url
http://stackoverflow.com/api/userimage.url?userid={userid}&photoid={photoid}
```

Could return "`ContentType: text`" with the url for the body.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/api/userimage/{userid}.html
http://stackoverflow.com/api/userimage.html?userid={userid}
```

Could show you where all of the redirects point to, and their descriptions.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/api/userimage/{userid}/{photoid}.what
http://stackoverflow.com/api/userimage.what?userid={userid}&photoid={photoid}
```

Could return "`ContentType: text`" with the description for the body.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/api/userimage/{userid}.json
http://stackoverflow.com/api/userimage.json?userid={userid}
```

---

You would have somewhere on your user-page where you can edit them.

---

This could be easily abused though.

It should have a limit to how many you can post in a day, or a forced delay between how often you can add another image.

Answer (score 0):

Just post your screenshot you take with any myriad of free screencap apps on any myriad of free image hosts.....  Don't clog up the S[O|U|F] servers with other crap.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the site would agree with you.  Where would all these pictures be stored? They would have to increase their hosting capabilities greatly to support built in picture hosting. Am I wrong? This site is meant to be quick and efficient and I believe this would not support that goal. There are so many other picture hosting options that I believe those should be used if needed. Otherwise, just quote the text of errors.